# How do you pronounce the word "married"?

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce the word "married"? Why do most people pronounce it like "mɛrid" or "mɛərid" even though IPA for it is "mærid"?

Comment: Pronunciation varies between BrEng and AmEng, as well as in different regional dialects. You should follow the pronunciation guide in the most relevant dictionary for where you live or are speaking English.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/married